# CSV header validation using supercsv

Tags: java, csv, supercsv

How can I validate that the data of CSV file contains headers? I am using supercsv and Java.   My csv file contains;

ACCOUNT,NAME,PHONE     (header)  <--- validation needed, all headers must present 
Checking,John,1122222222   (data)

Saving,Carl,1234567891    (data)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :) As @fge says, you really should document what you've tried. It makes it easier for others to answer, and you're more likely to get an upvote on your question.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't know what the header values are beforehand, there's no way to know if the first line is a header or not (it just looks like another data line).

If you *do* know what the header values should be, then you could simply make sure that all the expected columns are there (it doesn't matter what order, as long as they're there).

For example

```
List<String> expectedHeaders = Arrays.asList("ACCOUNT","NAME","PHONE");

String[] header = csvReader.getHeader(true);

if (!Arrays.asList(header).containsAll(expectedHeaders)){
    // not all headers present - handle appropriately 
    // (e.g. throw exception)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Hound Dog for your suggestion.

Comment: No problem @Dharanae, don't forget to select this as the correct answer (if it is!)